# Call to a member function getId() on null date.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, date, page-layouts

I want to call a `date.phtml` template in `catalog/product/view.phtml` but i have the error: `Call to a member function getId() on null in ...PATH` line 28 and this line there is : `<?php $_optionId = $_option->getId() ?>`

I called it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You block type is wrong

It should be

**catalog/product_view_options_type_date** from **core/template**

**So change:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_options_type_date')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: i tried this type before but i have the same problem error`Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml on line 28`